# SQL Web Edition Download location

Tags: sql-server

I cannot find the download location for SQL Web Edition.

I can find the [Standard](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) / Developer / Express editions, but not the Web edition.

I have tried https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads,
I have followed all the links on the page, and found various informational resources of SQL Web edition, but not the actual file.

Where/how can I download SQL Web Edition

Comment: Which version? AFAIK there is no Web edition for 2016.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web Edition is not available to download at will.

See [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2016-pricing).  Scroll half way down to 'SQL Server Price' section.

[image]

Comment: Hello. My hosting have licensing but they don't have 2019 ISO. they have 2017 ISO. So where can I find 2019 ISO?